# Visual Studio Macros: Loop through Selection, add .Append(" and ") to each line in selection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macros, visual-studio-macros

Found this:

```
Sub SurroundWithAppendTag()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = ".Append(""" + DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text + """)"
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to loop through each line of text in the selection. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
Dim lines = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, vbLf).Split(vbLf)
```

The rest is up to you...

Comment: @JaredPar does he want a full code? hehe :-P And what about some hard sweat?!

Comment: Got it, I believe. I'm assuming every line is pushed into lines, so I simply need to iterate and return?

Comment: sweating is bad when coding, it makes typing difficult :)